# How to achieve variable jump height in an elegant and natural way

Tags: physics, platformer

I am making a platformer, with a methodical approach to player physics. This is how I do variable jump height:

```
if not btn() then
   g_fall *= 1.5
end

if (not is_grounded) then
   // fall gravity
   p.ay = g_fall
end
```

`p` is the player, `p.ay` is the acceleration.

`g_fall` is the constant falling gravity, which I apply to the player's acceleration if it's not on the ground. If the player isn't pressing the jump button I increase `g_fall` so player falls down quicker thus achieving variable jump height.

This is somewhat ok, but I have a spring where player can jump and it bounces player to the air.

```
hit.y = ispring.y - 2
hit.dx *= 0.2
hit.dy=-v0_jump * 1.5
```

`hit` is the player, `v0_jump` is the constant initial velocity I give to the player to jump.

When the player presses jump while on the spring, it jumps higher because the fall gravity is lower. But I want spring to give you the same jump height whether you press jump or not.

Now I could put a flag for spring jump and an if condition to test for spring jumps and adjust the fall gravity, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

So what are some professional techniques for variable jump height that can solve my problem out of the box.

Comment: You may be interested in [Building a Better Jump](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023559/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Building)

Comment: @DMGregory There is so much knowledge in those old GDC talks

Comment: I've watched that and that's how I implemented my jump system, and that says to triple the gravity when the jump button isn't pressed which is what I did in my presented solution.